# Выбор хранилища для нового проекта

Tags: java, база-данных, json, nosql

Доброго времени суток! Нужна ваша помощь. Сразу прошу прощения, если уже где-то это было, но, честно, искал и ничего подходящего не нашел. Начинаем новый проект (java, spring, tomcat) и столкнулись с проблемой выбора хранилища. Дело в том, что данные у нас такого вида:

`[{id:1, name:"test", relationships: [1, 2, 3, 4], charges: [{name:"charge1", type:1, validFor: {from:"", to:""}}...]}]`

В общем, есть json под 1 Мб, в котором часть данных денормализованы и вложены в сам документ, а часть это идентификаторы других сущностей. Суть в том, что нам нужно хранить такой документ у себя и работать с ним (поиск по параметрам, редактирование и т.д.). Сначала попробовали положить все в PostgreSQL, так как есть реляция, но получилось что-то жуткое, около 200 таблиц и жуткие джойны в запросах, также столкнулись с проблемой, что сам документ и сущности, связанные с ним, часто меняются (добавляются и удаляются какие-то поля и связки с другими сущностями). Отсюда, решили, что в реляционку он плохо ложится, начали смотреть в сторону NoSQL и заглохли, так как опыта такого у нас нет, а вариантов куча. Думали, что можно денормализовать все данные, чтобы избавиться от реляции, но тогда получится, что при изменении общей сущности, нам придется пробежать по всем документам, которые содержат ее, а это, как нам кажется, не очень хорошая идея. Первое, что бросилось в глаза и что идеально подходит нам по функционалу, так это Amazon SimpleDb, но он платный и это сторонний сервис, заказчик никогда не согласится хранить свои данные на сторонних сервисах, поэтому все сервера должны быть у нас.

Поэтому вопрос №1: Что бы вы посоветовали, в принципе, для хранения таких данных и работы с ними?

Также, к сожалению, стоит задача хранения истории изменений каждого документа, включая сущности, связанные с ним, нужно, чтобы пользователь мог посмотреть историю изменений документа (что, кем и когда изменилось), при желании откатить их, а также посмотреть список всех документов и их изменений в рамках проекта (грубо говоря это название групповых изменений)

Отсюда вопрос № 2: Как лучше всего реализовать это в хранилище из вопроса 1?

Comment: elastic или mongodb, как вариант. Если у вас есть BIG DATA и HDFS - Solr. Сколько данных? Примерно

Comment: Честно говоря, дело пахнет холиваром. 200 таблиц само по себе не хорошо и не плохо, в любой банковской АБС с 200 таблиц все только начинается... И ничего, сидят себе на реляционных базах. И, как обычно, напрашивается "делайте на том, на чем умеете".

Comment: @Chubatiy, спасибо за ответ, данных немного, около 200 000. Монгу рассматривали, но, насколько я изучил ее, там нет нормальной транзакционности, а нам нужны групповые операции над документами, также чтобы резолвить отношения по идентификаторам, надо будет делать дополнительные запросы, и в ней есть ограничение на 16Мб документа, а если мы будем хранить историю изменений, то возможно и вылезем за эти пределы (при условии, что история будет храниться в самом документе)

Comment: @Dmitry, согласен с вами, 200 таблиц конечно же много, но жить можно, проблема не в их количестве, а в поддержке такого количества, дело в том, что новые поля и новые сущности со связями будут появляться часто (бизнес требования телекома быстро меняются) и каждый раз добавлять и удалять (переносить) колонки и создавать новые таблицы при миграции будет очень сложно, собственно поэтому и смотрим в хранилище с отсутствием строгой схемы.

Comment: В постгресе можно совместить обе модели. Там же есть массивы и возможность делать собственные композитные типы. Где хотите денормализовать -- определите тип записей Т и заведите колонку с типом "массив записей Т", а то, на что планируете ссылаться, вынесите в отдельную таблицу. Вы уже рассматривали эти возможности, или смотрели на постгрес только как на РСУБД без денормализации как таковой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Суть в том, что нам нужно хранить такой документ у себя и работать с
>   ним (поиск по параметрам, редактирование и т.д.).

Если структура документа не меняется в процессе работы приложения, т.е. ваш процесс такой - вы договорились о структуре документа приходящего в запросе и в случае изменения его структуры, выпускаете новую версию продукта который будет работать с новой версией запроса. Если так, то по этому свойству вам подходит и РСУБД. Если же формат данных может быть разным при каждом запросе, вряд ли РСУБД будет хорошим вариантом. РСУБД дает вам больше контроля за целостностью данных - контролирует пытки записать в ячейку таблицы данные не соответствующего типа, или не корректные данные в которых часть данных отсутствует. Касаемо NoSQL СУБД вам больше подходят документно-ориентированный тип, т.к. по сути ваш запрос и есть документ в формате JSON, который вы скорее всего в неизменном виде запишите в БД. Такая NoSQL как MongoDB напрямую работает с данными в JSON формате(по факту используется BSON), что позволяет вам сильно упростить операцию записи данных в БД и сосредоточится на разработке инструментов по анализу этих данных. Что по сути и требуется от вашего проекта. Исходя из выше написанного в случае выбора РСУБД вам потребуется потратить дополнительные ресурсы на разработку кода который будет трансформировать ваши данные в реляционный вид, а так же на разработку реляционного представления ваших данных - набора таблиц и связей между ними.

> но получилось что-то жуткое, около 200 таблиц и жуткие джойны в
>   запросах

Касаемо таблиц я сформулировал сравнение выше, в случае NoSQL БД хранящей данные в JSON вам не потребуется серьезных дополнительных усилий для записи данных. В случае денормализованной структуры с док.-ор. СУБД у вас есть два варианта решения проблемы:

1. Полная денормализация - тогда каждый документ будет хранить все
   составляющие его данные внутри себя и получение и изменение их будет
   простой задачей. Но вы столкнетесь с проблемами обновления общих
   сущностей для всего набора документов, т.к. каждый будет содержать
   её копии.
2. Все внешние сущности хранить в отдельных документах и ссылаться на
   них, подход схож с подходом РСУБД и по сути является попыткой
   нормализовать данные. В данном подходе возникнут те же трудности с
   "жуткие джойны в запросах" но решаться это будет не посредствам SQL
   языка а объединением нужных коллекций представляющих документы
   непосредственно в коде.

По сути оптимальным будет микс этих подходов, вы будите видеть где вам проще хранить данные в виде агрегатов а где использовать ссылки на общие сущности.

> также столкнулись с проблемой, что сам документ и сущности, связанные
>   с ним, часто меняются (добавляются и удаляются какие-то поля и связки
>   с другими сущностями).

Данная проблема, которая к тому же связана с предыдущей, может быть легко решена с помощью графовых БД, которые созданы с целю легкого управления множеством сущностей связанных между собой сложным образом. 
Так же существуют смешанные модели, которые сочетают графовый и документо-ориентированный подход - OrientDB. Этот подход может в вашем случае радикально упростить решение текущей задачи. Но важно понимать, что если ваша система будет обрастать новым функционалом этот подход может быть не оптимальным для нового функционала, и в этом случает вам следует добавить в систему ещё одну субд с подходящим типом - многовариантная персистентность.
Я думаю OrientDB или подобная система сочетающая графовый и док.-ориентированный подход, освободит вас от множества проблем связанных с несогласованностью ваших данные и структуры СУБД.

> Поэтому вопрос №1: Что бы вы посоветовали, в принципе, для хранения
>   таких данных и работы с ними?

Я бы вам посоветовал OrientDB или аналог. Да вам придется изучить новую технологию. Но крайне важно понимать что самые большие проблемы появляются когда проект уже запущен, устоялся и нужно его активно развивать. Из-за неудачного выбора модели в начале, с ростом сложности проекта, он обрастает проблемами как снежный ком, для внедрения/удаления/модификации нового поля или таблицы вам придется приложить невероятное кол-во усилий, так же для модифиция запросов которые будет затрагивать это изменение.
Мой вывод выбирайте систему хранения данных которая будет наиболее естественной для вашей задачи и сосредоточьтесь на решении задачи - анализе данных.

> Также, к сожалению, стоит задача хранения истории изменений каждого
>   документа, включая сущности, связанные с ним, нужно, чтобы
>   пользователь мог посмотреть историю изменений документа (что, кем и
>   когда изменилось), при желании откатить их, а также посмотреть список
>   всех документов и их изменений в рамках проекта (грубо говоря это
>   название групповых изменений)

Многие NoSQL СУБД поддерживают встроенный механизм аудита - MongoDB, OrientDB, оба при покупке коммерческой лицензии. Но вы можете поискать решение от коммьюнити или написать самостоятельно.

Подытоживая:

Исходя из описанной вами проблемы, вам подходит СУБД - смесь графовой и документо-ориентированной(оптимально, хранящей данные в JSON). Потому что у вас все данные изначально представлены в JSON и имеют множество связей между собой. Вам привел пример такой СУБД, можете посмотреть в сторону альтернатив.

Перед выбором я вам советую почитать книгу(не большую по размеру) - "NoSQL. Новая методология разработки не реляционных баз данных". Перевод на русский несколько кривоват, но достаточен для понимания что вам могут дать NoSQL БД.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, мы, действительно, открыли для себя графовые хранилища и видится, что это решение наших проблем, сейчас рассматриваем Neo4j, но воспользуемся вашим советом и рассмотрим еще OrientDB.